# deploying rails application on Windows Azure (Unicorn and NginX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, unicorn, ubuntu-server

### How can I figure out what is going wrong with my deployment?

I was following the well written tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04.

Everything ran smoothly for me up until I started using NginX to run the server.  When I got to the point where I ran the command `RAILS_ENV=production rails server --binding=server_public_IP`, I was able to hop over to another machine on the network and visit the page with the browser.

Once I got to the end, I felt like I got there with no hiccups or anything, but I can't get the page to come up anymore and I don't know how to figure out what is wrong.  I'm assuming my server is running, but here is some useful information:

when I run service status on nginx:

```
<user>@aws-ubuntu:~/<app>$ sudo service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-10-22 23:33:32 UTC; 16min ago
  Process: 2797 ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2794 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --signal QUIT --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2806 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2804 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2826 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2809 Passenger watchdog
           ├─2812 Passenger core
           ├─2817 Passenger ust-router
           ├─2826 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           ├─2827 nginx: worker process
           ├─2828 nginx: worker process
           ├─2829 nginx: worker process
           └─2830 nginx: worker process

Oct 22 23:33:32 aws-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 22 23:33:32 aws-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Oct 22 23:33:32 aws-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

when I run service status on `unicorn_<app>`:

```
<user>@aws-ubuntu:~/<app>$ sudo service unicorn_<app> status
● unicorn_<app>.service - LSB: starts the unicorn app server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/unicorn_<app>)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2015-10-22 23:33:39 UTC; 18min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2847 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/unicorn_<app> stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2848 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/unicorn_<app> start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 22 23:33:35 aws-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts the unicorn app server...
Oct 22 23:33:35 aws-ubuntu unicorn_<app>[2848]: Starting <app>
Oct 22 23:33:35 aws-ubuntu su[2849]: Successful su for <user> by root
Oct 22 23:33:35 aws-ubuntu su[2849]: + ??? root:<user>
Oct 22 23:33:35 aws-ubuntu su[2849]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user <user> by (uid=0)
Oct 22 23:33:39 aws-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: starts the unicorn app server.
```

netstat for port:

```
<user>@aws-ubuntu:~/<app>$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2826/nginx -g daemo
```

Endpoint on Azure:
[image]

And finally, I don't know if this helps, but this is the server actually being able to respond from within:

```
<user>@aws-ubuntu:~/<app>$ curl localhost:8080/tasks
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><App></title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-e17d3eb99df904ad26a6d0d744384921.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-9eda54d248a655ae0a4b2932bd94d30b.js"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="mZeiuMQNcRe31Eiy1asvCeTDIXGrByjCt/DwWQzDL+E=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Listing tasks</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<a href="/tasks/new">New Task</a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```